# Angular 2 can not print array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Hello i started working a bit with angular 2 but i came across problem, and after playing a bit i discovered that i cannot even alert the length of my array. I'm missing something obvious but it works in edge (it always prints out the value) but not on chrome, i get this error [Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter]

Here is my code snippet:

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit{
coils : ICoil[];
constructor(private _loadCoil : LoadCoil){

}

ngOnInit() : void{
    this._loadCoil.getAllCoils().subscribe(coils => this.coils = coils ); 
    alert(this.coils.length);
}}
```

So as i have told this always alerts the length value when i test it in edge however it won't alert in chrome.
Thanks for help

Comment: Show us your ICoil interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is probably giving an error and that why you can't see the length of undefined. Because you are not initializing your array.

Either initialize it  like: `coils : ICoil[] = [];`

**or**

```
ngOnInit() : void{
    this._loadCoil.getAllCoils().subscribe(coils => this.coils = coils ); 
    alert(this.coils.length);
}}
```

should be

```
ngOnInit() : void{
    this._loadCoil.getAllCoils().subscribe((coils) => {
         this.coils = coils; 
         alert(this.coils.length);
     }); 

}}
```

`getAllCoils` is an async function.

Meaning it will take some time for its callback (subscribe) to execute. Therefore your `this.coils` will  be undefined until then.

Comment: Well it still should alert the length of the array as it does on edge, that what i'm asking

Comment: @Proxy Your code is probably giving an error and that why you can't see the length of undefined. Because you are not initializing your array.

Comment: Ah yeah like usual i forgot the most obvious thing... Thanks

Comment: @Proxy glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `subscribe` function will work after the `alert`. Because it is an `asynchronous` call. So the it 's content will work when the `this._loadCoil.getAllCoils()` will return the data.

Put the alert into the `subscribe` function

```
ngOnInit() : void{
    this._loadCoil.getAllCoils().subscribe(coils => {
        this.coils = coils; 
         alert(this.coils.length);
    });    
}}
```

Comment: i thought that but why does it then alert the value in edge and not on chrome?

Comment: And what it alerts in Edge?

Answer (score 1):

**getAllCoils** is asycnchronous so put the alert call in the subscribe callback.

```
ngOnInit() : void{
 this._loadCoil.getAllCoils().subscribe(coils => {
  this.coils = coils;
  alert(this.coils.length);
 });      
}}
```